# Why does GIT not use the core.editor and commit.template configuration values when running from the bash command prompt?

Tags: windows, git, bash, cmd

When I run commit from a standard command prompt it is opening the configured editor defined by the `core.editor` configuration value and uses the template defined by `commit.template`.

However when I run commit from the bash command prompt it is ignoring these settings and opening the `VI` editor without the template.  Why is this?

I am not so worried about the editor but I need to define the commit template.

Comment: I think you are talking about CMD.EXE on Windows as the "standard command prompt", I've re-tagged the question appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those settings are global ones (i.e. defined in "`$HOME/.gitconfig`" file rather than in your local repository `.git/config` file), that means they are defined in your `HOME`.
That "home" can differ between the windows session (cmd) and the bash session.
Check the value of `$HOME` in your bash session.

1. It should be defined
2. you should see a `.gitconfig` file in the directory referenced by your `$HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using the Git Bash shell.  I set the environment variable GIT_EDITOR to the path of the editor you want to use.  Then after a reboot git started using my default editor.

```
GIT_EDITOR = "C:\Program Files (x86)\e\e.exe"
```

Hope that helps.